# How to type a circumflex for programming

Tags: internationalization

maybe this is a silly question but im trying to type

`self.router[@"say/hello"] =  ^ {
        NSLog(@"Hello World!");
};`

and i cant type this character ^

I tried with:

- option + i = ˆ
- shift + 6 = ˆ

please help i'm a bit bored o copy and paste every time.

Comment: Are you using the US International PC keyboard layout?  If so, stop and switch to plain US.  Then Shift + 6 will do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch from using the US International PC layout to the US layout.  Then Shift + 6 will generate ^.